# Surfaces with many (but not solely) closed geodesics?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, surfaces

Let $S$ be a closed surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
let's say of genus zero.
I seek examples of $S$ with the following property:
If one selects <strike>a random</strike> *any* point $p$ on $S$, and a random
direction $u$ tangent to $S$ at $p$, then the geodesic
issuing from $p$ in direction $u$ is a closed geodesic with
positive probability.
[Question modified to reflect @alvarezpaiva's comment.]

I know this is trivially true for Zoll surfaces,
on which *every* geodesic is closed; see figure below.
But are there non-Zoll $S$ where geodesics are prevalent
enough to yield a positive probability (perhaps $1$)?
Or, to be more explicit:

> **Q**. If, for every $p \in S$, closed geodesics issuing from $p$
>   occur with probablility $1$ among all tangent directions $u$,
>   does that imply that *every* such geodesic is closed?

[image: ZollDiscr]

          
<sub>(Zoll Surface: Image from [Polthier&Schmies](http://www-sfb288.math.tu-berlin.de/Research/GEODESICS/Geodesic.html) via [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/150564/6094))</sub>

Comment: Well, just take a metric on the two-sphere that agrees with the standard metric in a neighborhood of an equator. How about asking that at *every* point $p$ there is a positive probability that a geodesic through $p$ be closed?

Comment: @alvarezpaiva: Ah, good point! I have so modified the question.

Comment: By the way, your "sub-question" asking for surfaces where with probability one a unit vector is the initial condition of a closed geodesic looks very interesting. I wonder if there is anything besides surfaces all of whose geodesics are closed.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva: Yes, actually, that is the heart of my question, which I initially misphrased. I think examples would be interesting if the answer is *Yes*, and perhaps even more interesting if the answer is *No*.

Comment: If you substitute dense for probability one, it will **not** be the same problem. I think that if you take a metric of revolution on the sphere the initial conditions for closed geodesics may be dense in the unit tangent bundle (the invariant tori with rational rotation numbers are foliated by periodic orbits).

Comment: @alvarezpaiva: Thank you for the correction. I naively assumed "dense" and "probability 1" were equivalent. I have revised (again!). It's now as much your problem as mine. :-)

Comment: It's related to something I worked on, but for Finsler metrics. It turns out that there are continuous Finsler metrics on the torus, for  example, that are smooth almost everywhere and for which with probability one every unit momentum is the initial condition of a closed geodesic of length 1. This has neat applications to the geometry of numbers. See this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132818/zoll-flat-finsler-tori-and-convex-bodies-on-a-starry-night